# Generalize $\mathbb Z/p$-space for irrational $\alpha$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

A free $\mathbb Z/p$-space is a topological space $X$ with an action $\varphi$ such that $\forall x\in X$ $\varphi^p(x)=x$ but $\varphi(x)\ne x$.
I would like to generalize this notion from $\frac 1p$ to irrational $\alpha$ in the following way.

> > $(X,\varphi)$ is a free $\alpha$-space if $\forall x\in X$ $\varphi^{a_n}(x)\to x$ if and only if $a_n\alpha\to 0 \pmod 1$.

Have these spaces been studied? Are there any theorems similar to (the generalizations of) Borsuk-Ulam for such spaces?

Caveat: This is not my field, I'm just looking for possible combinatorial applications, so please show mercy when answering!

Comment: My edit might come across as pedantic, but $\mathbb Z_p$ is also used to denote the $p$-adic integers, and that made the question more confusing. If you feel strongly about the edit, feel free to revert.

Comment: I think that may be, you should start thinking in what does it means a rational action. On the other way, the definition of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ free action relies on that the group is cyclic. Also , your definition seems interesting.

Comment: How do you calcule the power elevated at the sequence? I asume that is a rational sequence with an extra condition.

Comment: @Murphy I supposed that $a_n\in \mathbb N$, if your question was about that.

Comment: I think Murphy is right in saying that the definition of the action relies on the fact that $\mathbb{Z}/p$ is cyclic. Perhaps a condition such as the density of union of orbits is required (which might be equivalent to your definition) ! I would suggest to talk to people in dynamical systems as they are very much interested in this kind of phenomena and it is still a topic of interest for these people! I believe even in the case of circle, $X=S^1$, studying such `actions' is still an active area of research in dynamical systems.